# Gulp run and watch

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-watch

I've just started playing with gulp. How would the following be combined?

```
gulp.src('src')
  .pipe(traceur())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));

watch('src')
  .pipe(traceur())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
```

Is there a more standard way than using a `[gulp.src('src'), watch('src')]` array with foreach?

Answer (score 0):

you can use gulp-watch plugin like so:

```
var watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.src('src')
    .pipe(watch('src'))
    .pipe(traceur())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
```

gulp-watch will pass all files on first run, and then only changed ones after that.